# Dart catch http exceptions

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using http package of dart to make post requests. Due to some server issues its throwing exception. I have wrapped the code in a try catch block code but it's not catching the exception.

Here's the code which makes network request

```
  class VerificationService {

  static Future<PhoneVerification> requestOtp(
      PhoneNumberPost phoneNumberPostData) async {
    final String postData = jsonEncode(phoneNumberPostData);
    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        getPhoneRegistrationApiEndpoint(),
        headers: {'content-type': 'Application/json'},
        body: postData,
      );
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        return PhoneVerification.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception('Request Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } on Exception {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

A function of a separate class using the above static method.

```
void onButtonClick() {

try {
    VerificationService.requestOtp(PhoneNumberPost(phone))
        .then((PhoneVerification onValue) {
      //Proceed to next screen
    }).catchError((Error onError){
      enableInputs();
    });
  } catch(_) {
    print('WTF');
  }
}
```

In the above method, the exception is never caught. 'WTF' is never printed on the console. What am I doing wrong here? I am new to dart.

Comment: Use `async`/`await` instead of `then`, then `try`/`catch` will work.

Comment: Can you please submit a code snippet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `async`/`await` instead of `then`, then `try`/`catch` will work

```
void onButtonClick() async {
  try {
    var value = await VerificationService.requestOtp(PhoneNumberPost(phone))
  } catch(_) {
    enableInputs();
    print('WTF');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

This is a supplemental answer for other people searching for how to catch http exceptions.

It's good to catch each kind of exception individually rather than catching all exceptions generally. Catching them individually allows you to handle them appropriately.

Here is a code snippet adapted from [Proper Error Handling in Flutter & Dart](https://resocoder.com/2019/12/11/proper-error-handling-in-flutter-dart-1-principles/)

```dart
// import 'dart:convert' as convert;
// import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode != 200) throw HttpException('${response.statusCode}');
  final jsonMap = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
} on SocketException {
  print('No Internet connection ');
} on HttpException {
  print("Couldn't find the post ");
} on FormatException {
  print("Bad response format ");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that SocketException is the part of the dart::io but dart::io is not available on the web client (but dart:http is available).

Comment: How do you know that these are the only exceptions that can be thrown?

Comment: @Ubiux, I'm not positive that these are the only exceptions that can be thrown, although they're the only ones I known of right now. You could add a `catch` block and catch everything else, but then if there is another kind of exception that you didn't know about, it would just be ignored silently and you still wouldn't know about it. Instead of that, it's better to let that unknown exception crash your app. Then you'll know about it and can handle it appropriately.